# Web console script to keep variable numbers of id constant

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, angularjs

I am an amateur web developer and I have a challenge.
I am trying to make a javascript that will keep a variable number ranging 0-9 constant. Example, the html script  and the id, xyz generates random numbers 0-9 from the database. I need help to create a javascript to be put in web console of a browser(eg Google chrome. Ctrl   Shift   J ) to keep the variable numbers constant. Lets say 5 always.

Comment: var ini = 5;
document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = ini;

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage like below:

```
localStorage.setItem('name','nadim');

alert(localStorage.getItem('name'));
```

Comment: Can you explain, like what I should put in place of "name" and "nadim"

Comment: name is the key and nadim is value ... when you save any string into key .. you can use it anywhere  after store

Comment: It only gives me alert on my screen